# Issue in Creating file pattern to get the file path from azure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I am trying to load parquet file from Azure storage account to Snowflake tables using  (Stage & Pipe), but my file path is dynamic (Year/Month/Day/Hour/File. parquet) every time it will be changing, I need solution for this.

```
     create or replace pipe Test
     auto_ingest = true
     integration = 'TestNI'
     as
     copy into DB.stg.Test
     from @Test_STAGE/
     PATTERN = '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/Test'
     file_format = PARQUET
     MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = 'CASE_INSENSITIVE'
     ON_ERROR = 'SKIP_FILE';
```

I have tried Date_part, concat its not working inside the copy statement.
And I have tried with the pattern '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/Test' , as it is working but it is generating duplicates .

As I mentioned my file path is dynamic and it is changing every hour, if the pipe runs then it is loading all the files.

Comment: I think you do not need to use the "PATTERN" for dynamic PATH. It will be loading anything under the @Test_STAGE/ location, including sub directories. The Pattern is needed if you want to exclude/include some files which are in the same directories.